# Google firebase Field can not be added. It may already be registered on another project

Tags: android, firebase

I get this error "Field can not be added. It may already be registered on another project" when I add url address. However I don't have another project but still, I am getting this error  is there any way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Did you have an earlier project with the same name that you have deleted?

Comment: I guess yes I think so but why still  I m getting this error ?

Comment: how can I solve this problem. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you had a project earlier with the same name and same structure and when you are trying to add a new field, you get that error. This also is happening because when you delete a project, you don't delete it in real time. It takes time till everything will be clean.

To solve this problem, create a fresh new project, download the `json` file again and copy that in your app project.

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes but it was 2 or more than 2 weeks ego. 10 times I create  a new fresh project but it still gives the same error ?

Comment: I don't know the exact amount of time but i had the same problem and it took more than two weeks. If you add it over and over again with the same name, the problem will persist. If you added today than more than two week from now you'll need to wait. It advice you to send your problem also to the Firebase team [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/).

Comment: Thank you for all your helps